# How to create a FTP Server on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: vsftpd

I have to create a FTP server for multiple users. Each user should have the capability to upload, download and delete content.

What are the steps needed in order to create such server? I have absolutely no knowledge on the subject.

Comment: Could you tell us what you've already tried? Note that there's no FileZilla server for Ubuntu, but of course there are plenty of others which all are pretty well documented (proftpd for example).

Comment: I've submitted an edit for this title, as he wants users to be able to use the FileZilla client, so the title is misleading. I do suggest a google search for this, or even some apress books on ubuntu server administration. even openssh comes w/ sftp which works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well I would use sftp which is available in the OpenSSH package, FileZilla clients can connect to the server on the ssh port.

Comment: This is certainly the best option if you don't need fine grained account control.  SSHD 5.x+  has the FTP subsystem included.

Comment: my thinking is using either a directory for large users or adding them to the Ubuntu OS, and assigning folder permissions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be FileZilla?

If not, you can use [vsftpd](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html), which is well documented on Ubuntu's help pages.

Comment: vsftpd is unnecessary though if you already have the SSHD daemon enabled.   I wouldn't use vsftpd unless i first determine that the SSHD FTP subsystem insn't enough.

Comment: @djangofan True enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at [CrushFTP](http://crushftp.com/index.html)  This is a very full featured package that allows may connection methods.  Great support even during the free trial.